# The jest error report displays the wrong error location

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

When I use jest for unit testing, I write the correct test cases and everything looks fine after running jest.

My test case:

```js
  it('isString', () => {
    expect(isString('string')).toBeTruthy();
    expect(isString(1)).toBeFalsy();
    expect(isBoolean(NaN)).toBeFalsy();
    expect(isString(true)).toBeFalsy();
    expect(isString(null)).toBeFalsy();
    expect(isString(undefined)).toBeFalsy();
    expect(isString({})).toBeFalsy();
    expect(isString([])).toBeFalsy();
    expect(isString(new Set())).toBeFalsy();
    expect(isString(new Map())).toBeFalsy();
    expect(isString(Symbol(1))).toBeFalsy();
    expect(
      isString(() => {
        /* */
      }),
    ).toBeFalsy();
  });
```

But I want to know what it will look like when the test case goes wrong，so I modified a use case

```js
  it('isString', () => {
    expect(isString('string')).toBeTruthy();
>--  expect(isString(1)).toBeFalsy();
>++  expect(isString(1)).toBeTruthy();
    expect(isBoolean(NaN)).toBeFalsy();
    expect(isString(true)).toBeFalsy();
    expect(isString(null)).toBeFalsy();
    expect(isString(undefined)).toBeFalsy();
    expect(isString({})).toBeFalsy();
    expect(isString([])).toBeFalsy();
    expect(isString(new Set())).toBeFalsy();
    expect(isString(new Map())).toBeFalsy();
    expect(isString(Symbol(1))).toBeFalsy();
    expect(
      isString(() => {
        /* */
      }),
    ).toBeFalsy();
  });
```

Obviously this is not as expected and it points to another test case, I got the following error：

```
FAIL  utils/type/index.test.ts (9.957 s)
● type › isString

    expect(received).toBeTruthy()
    
    Received: false
    
      21 |     expect(typeOf(1)).toBe('number');
      22 |     expect(typeOf(true)).toBe('boolean');
    > 23 |     expect(typeOf(null)).toBe('null');
         |                                          ^
      24 |     expect(typeOf(undefined)).toBe('undefined');
      25 |     expect(typeOf({})).toBe('object');
      26 |     expect(typeOf([])).toBe('array');
    
      at Object.<anonymous> (utils/type/index.test.ts:23:42)
```

The error I expected should be as follows

```
FAIL  utils/type/index.test.ts (9.957 s)
● type › isString

    expect(received).toBeTruthy()
    
    Received: false
    
      38 |     expect(isString('string')).toBeTruthy();
    > 39 |     expect(isString(1)).toBeTruthy();
         |                         ^
      40 |     expect(isBoolean(NaN)).toBeFalsy();
      41 |     expect(isString(true)).toBeFalsy();
      42 |     expect(isString(null)).toBeFalsy();
    
      at Object.<anonymous> (utils/type/index.test.ts:23:42)
```

I upgraded [jest](/questions/tagged/jest) and [ts-jest](/questions/tagged/ts-jest) to the latest version

- jest: 29.7.0
- ts-jest: 29.1.1

Here is my Jest config

```js
import path from 'path';

export default {
  collectCoverage: true,
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    '<rootDir>/utils/**/*.ts',
    '!<rootDir>/utils/*.ts',
    '!<rootDir>/**/*.test.ts',
  ],
  coverageDirectory: 'coverage',
  coveragePathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/'],

  rootDir: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../../'),
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  testMatch: ['<rootDir>/utils/**/*.test.ts'],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/'],
  transform: {
    '\\.ts$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/', '\\.pnpm?\\.[^\\/]+$'],
};
```